# Avoiding edge repeats in a FFT convolution

Tags: fft, image-processing, convolution

I am trying to use FFT as a fast way to convolve a image, however one of the downsides of this is that the "kernel" image will repeat when reaching the edges of the sample.

Is there a way to avoid this to make it more like a classic convolution, that cuts off at the edges?

[image: Edge repeating]

Answer (score 2):

Zero-pad the edges of the image, then truncate the excess edge from the result

Comment: While you answer is correct, it would be good to add how much to zero-pad, truncate, etc.